# Getting two error's in nodejs using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

(I know this has a bad title)
I'm using firebase and express for this project but this doesn't work.

src/index.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { doc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { collection, addDoc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import Chance from "chance";
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

var chance = new Chance();
const expressApp = express();

expressApp.set('view engine', 'ejs');

expressApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("hello");
    res.render('index');
});

expressApp.post('/add', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    add(req.body.name);
    res.send(`You said ${req.body.name}`);
    res.status(200);
});


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "apikey",

    authDomain: "authDomain",

    projectId: "projectId",

    storageBucket: "storageBucket",

    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",

    appId: "appId",

    measurementId: "measurementId"

};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);


async function add(firstName) {
    try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
            first: firstName,
            last: chance.last(),
            born: chance.year({ min: 1920, max: 2000 }),
        },);
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
}



expressApp.listen(3000);

//add();
```

(Everything in the firebase config is actually there in my real js file)

src/views/index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="input" type="text" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
            const input = document.getElementById("input");
            fetch("/add", {
                method: "post",
                body: {
                    name: input.value,
                },
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => console.log(data));
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

In my terminal I'm getting this error

> Error adding document:  [FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field first in document users/VI9jpmKrASca4PhrTxYC)] {
> code: 'invalid-argument',
> customData: undefined,
> toString: [Function (anonymous)]
> }

and in my console(firefox) Im getting this

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

also if I use insomnia or rest clinet and pass in an object like
{
"name":"hello",
}
it works properly

Comment: Try `body: JSON.stringify({ name: input.value })` in your fetch request. Also add a `console.log(input.value)` to check if value is correct.

Comment: I still get the same error and I get the same text in my input from the console.log

Comment: The error arises because at least one of the value in addDoc is undefined. It'll be best if you try to log them in `add()` function like `console.log(firstName, chance.last(), chance.year({ min: 1920, max: 2000 }))`. can you share the output of this log statement?

Comment: ok I have to sleep rn but tommorow morning I will

Comment: and chance is a library for random

Comment: If I put something anything in my input it shows undefined, a random last name and year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it!

So for some reason if I put const data = { name: input.value } and put body: JSON.stringify(data) it works properly

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field first in document users/VI9jpmKrASca4PhrTxYC)]

Is telling you that the document field named `first` contains `undefined`, which is invalid in Firestore.  You will need to make sure that you pass a correct value when you call `addDoc`.

We can't debug this for you because we can't see the value of `req.body.name` that you're using here:

```
add(req.body.name);
```

Comment: If I put something anything in my input it shows undefined

Comment: OK, well, undefined values are invalid for Firestore, so you're going to have to debug more to figure out why that is.  We can't do that for you using what you've shown so far.

Comment: How? I've shown all my code

Comment: Add debug logging wherever you think the value that should not be undefined, and show us what you learned.

Comment: I did it and in the ejs file it shows the value but in the req.body.name it shows undefined

Comment: What about index.js where the value comes from?

Comment: ? The value comes from the index.ejs file not index.js

Comment: You should log the value of interest anywhere it occurs to figure out where the value is first something other than what you expect.  This is all part of debugging.  Your question should explain all of your observations and what you do to reproduce the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I log everywhere where I use it but it the index.js file it shows as undefined

Comment: I tried console.log(req.body) but it gives me an empty object {} for some reason